# which data structure is recommended for returning two values

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I am implementing a method that should returns two values "sum and indexArray". Is there any data structure, aside from `Hashmap`, by which I can store these two values and consequently the method returns it.?

Note:

sum is of `int` datatype

indexArray is of  `int[]`

Comment: A tuple? An instance of a holder class? It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: What are the types? I would assume that sum is a numeric and indexArray is an array of ints, but this is just a guess.

Comment: @JonKiparsky your guess is correct. i also added a note to my qestion

Comment: In that case, you're going to need a class to hold both of these values. (technically you COULD use an array of Object, and store the int as an Integer - but you really don't want to do that)

Comment: Just scan the array and sum the values into an int variable. Then you have both the array of ints and its total. You might want to enclose this into an object and provide a `getTotal()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to return an int and a array . Your questions needs a bit more clarity . There is no java collection that you can use that would hold both. Create a java class with the two as the instance members and pass the instance of that class

Comment: that's what i thought

Answer (score 1):

I would simple create a class to hold the two values being returned, like an inner class unless it has usefulness elsewhere.

You could use a list, each odd element is your sum and each even element your indexArray

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what do you mean by indexArray, is it an int value ?
if so , then you can work with 2d array with 2 column a, you can also create a special objects with 2 values for example x & y .

Answer (score 1):

For Android, I think maybe [**Pair**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) util is suitable for this case.

Comment: nice one, no need to implement tuples anymore!

Answer (score 0):

1-(Integer...) it's means array of integer
2-(list )which first item with index 0 the sum and your array be next.

```
 List <Integer> data=new ArrayList <Integer>();
 data.add (sum);
 //then loop on array and add your data in the list finally return list
```